# Moloquent laravel hasOne & hasMany not working with foreignKey in ObjectId

Tags: laravel, mongodb, moloquent

I'm Using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` library in my Laravel MongoDB application. However, the  `hasOne` relationship is only working if `foreignKey` in a string. if it saves as a ObjectId type, the relationship gives an empty result.

MongoDB document user_profile

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c40307107928879107d8ee3"),
    "first_name" : "Alert",
    "last_name" : "CB",
    "speciality" : null,
    "company" : ObjectId("5b8cd8bc0176533ff65c4c62"),
    "platform_start_date" : "2019-01-17",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-01-17T13:40:37.000+05:30"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-01-17T13:06:17.000+05:30")
}
```

Company document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8cd8bc0176533ff65c4c62"),
    "name" : "ABCDEF",
    "contact" : "Dani",
    "notes" : "Test Note for builders....",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-09-03T12:16:20.000+05:30"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-09-03T12:16:20.000+05:30")
}
```

In UserProfile model

```
class UserProfile extends Moloquent
{
public function companies() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Company', 'company', '_id' );
    }
```

Currently this `companies()` give empty array, How to solve this and get the results ?
I'm using jenssegers/mongodb: 3.4.2

Comment: Can you swap the localkey and foreignkey parameters and try again?

Comment: @TahaPaksu it will give exception "Illegal offset type in isset or empty" in the controller that related to this

Comment: Did you try it before? HasMany relation had these parameters reversed, maybe moloquent implemented that in the reverse order too.

Comment: @TahaPaksu yes, This is working when company foreignkey is a string. but if it ObjectId, gives empty.

Comment: Then convert it to string when saving it? (the company field) Guess it has something to do with indexing?

Comment: @TahaPaksu  Yes, we need indexing. That's why try to do this.

Comment: Well after some research, the most reliable way would use a string column to build the relation, and add the index to it. This library doesn't support relations with ObjectId, but you can use aggregate queries with it. But it won't have the relation features.